# SVG symbols for alphabet characters e.g. A, B, C, ... etc

Tags: arcmap, svg, symbology

Can anyone tell me whether there is a SVG plugin or source (or how to do) of letters of the alphabet e.g. A, B, C, D etc.

I want to create a symbology with colour e.g. gray but also with letters in the fill pattern e.g. SI to denote "Semi-improved" grassland. Ideally trying to create JNCC phase 1 habitat symbols.

Thanks
Will

Comment: Have you tried to convert a font (e.g. Arial) to SVG and work with that?

Comment: Hi Bennos, can you do that in Word or do you need to use some online converting software? Thanks Will

Comment: Honestly I've never done that before, but I guess it won't work in Word. A quick searched for "font to svg" gave me some online converters, maybe it will work with that ...

Comment: Despite the other answer (on making font markers) I agree that a set of SVG symbols for this would be useful. We've tried to use font markers for letter combinations (e.g. "SI") and had problems - for use in QGIS. A test on QGIS with "SI" as an SVG symbol worked well. When we have time we may resort to generating the symbols ourselves.

Comment: SVG code for letter symbols now available in my proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I found the simple solution (eventually). You need to add a point patten fill over a simple fill. Change the point patten fill Symbol layer type to "Font marker". Then chose your font required e.g. Times new roman and the letter/symbol you require e.g. "A" for amenity grassland (JNCC, 1990).

Answer (score 1):

An SVG symbol containing just text is easy to create. SVG graphics are generated from a text file.

I'm no expert on SVG but the following seems to work. I've only tested it quickly, but it seems to work well on QGIS SVG marker fill - and solves problems we had with fills using multiple font marker letters.

Remember that you need to tell QGIS where to find your SVG files. On QGIS 2.6 this is here: (Settings | Options | System | SVG Paths).

To create the SVG marker copy the following into a text file, and save it with .svg rather than .txt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg height="40" width="40">
<text x="15" y="25" font-size="12" fill="black" font-family="sans">SI</text>
</svg>
```

This makes one symbol (with the letters SI). You'll be able to open this image in many applications (e.g. a web browser) but note that it's small. You change the symbol as follows...

- To change the density and size of the lettering use the "texture width" setting in QGIS.
- To change how closely spaced the lettering is without changing its size you need to alter the height="40" width="40" settings (these being the height and width of the overall symbol which includes the white space around the letters).
- If you want to put letters in an odd combination, like one F immediately above another F, duplicate the line starting and ending with the words text (put the new line immediately below the existing one) and alter the 'x="15" y="25"' which specifies the position of the text in the image - e.g. to y='35'.
- There are alternative font options in addition to 'font-family="sans"' : see this [SVG basics website](http://www.svgbasics.com/using_fonts.html) for ideas.
- I specified 'fill="black"' and you can obviously change this too for an alternate font colour. Again take a look at the SVG basics website for details.

These symbols can easily be combined with what looks like simple colour fills for the JNCC symbology available from several sources e.g. [here](https://github.com/QGIS-UK/Styles/tree/master/Phase%201%20Habitat)

I'm happy if anyone wants to add improvements to the SVG... but note that I've tried to keep the SVG coding as simple as possible to make it easy to understand.